# Explanation of ARTICLE tag

Tags: html, html5, articles

In explanation of  tag [W3SCHOOL](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_article.asp) :

> The  tag defines external
>   content.

What's the meaning of **external content** exactly ? It's mean *quoted (from somewhere) text* ?

Answer (score 2):

From the [HTML 5 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-article-element):

> The article element represents a
>   component of a page that consists of a
>   self-contained composition in a
>   document, page, application, or site
>   and that is intended to be
>   independently distributable or
>   reusable, e.g. in syndication. This
>   could be a forum post, a magazine or
>   newspaper article, a blog entry, a
>   user-submitted comment, an interactive
>   widget or gadget, or any other
>   independent item of content.

Answer (score 0):

The content within the `<article>` tag is independent from the other content of the site (even though it can be related).
In other words, The article element represents a component of a page that consists of self-contained composition in a document, page or a site
Reference by:[Geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html5-article-tag/)